# Exchange API Azure - Mailbox access ('full_access_as_app' is a major problem, how to scope to specific mailboxes)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices, azure-api-apps

I'm currently accessing Exchange API through OAuth access token.

However I had to select 
**'full_access_as_app by using Exchange Web Services with full access to all mailboxes'**

Is it possible to restrict the scope of mailboxes in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You might switch to MS Graph and use [Application Access Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access#configure-applicationaccesspolicy) which allows you to limit access to a specific set of mailboxes or none.

Comment: Exchange Online does not currently support ApplicationAccessPolicies for EWS's full_access_as_app scope.

Comment: @Alfredo -  Issue we're facing is : Application Access Policies only works with 'Graph API' and not the 'Exchange API'

Comment: @Sivaprakash -MSFT:  Is there is no other way to control the specific mailboxes the app can access? Considering, 'full_access_as_app' seems to be a major issue with our client

Answer (score 0):

As of 02/02/21 this is no longer a limitation of EWS. Based on [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/application-access-policy-support-in-ews/ba-p/2110361) announcement, Application Access Policies can now be used in conjunction with EWS API OAuth based application access.

> Using an application access policy, EWS administrators can now limit an app’s access to a specific set of mailboxes by specifying an inclusion or exclusion list. Administrators who want to limit third party app access to a specific set of mailboxes can use [New-ApplicationAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps) PowerShell cmdlet to configure access control. For more information about application access policies, see [Scoping application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access).